# Battery and Touchpad issues with ThinkPad P14s

Tags: fedora, i3, touchpad, thinkpad, battery

I am the happy owner of a Thinkpad P14s Gen1 with a AMD CPU since march 2021.

The problems I am going to describe occurred both with Ubuntu Gnome and Fedora xfce4 desktop environnement using i3wm.

Problem 1:

The battery self-discharges when the computer is shut down (which theoretically is normal). But the discharging rate seems high. Here is the last test I have made :

```
shutdown for 10 hours-> 8% lost // shutdown method :  command 'shutdown now'
shutdown for 10 hours-> 8% lost // shutdown method :  hardware shutdown button
shutdown for 4,5 hours-> 5% lost // shutdown method :  exit i3wm, and use the software shutdown button
```

Things you need to know:

```
I configure tlp so the battery charging stop right before 80%. I read that using the battery between 40% ans 80% was a good way to optimize battery life. And for some reasons I don’t understand, even after a complete new distribution installation, this setting persist (which is fine to me, but curious).
```

Problem 2:

Sometimes, when I start the computer, the touchpad is not responding at all.
The cursor is working with the little red guy or with an external mouse.

xinput output is the same whether touchpad is working or not, here it is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                      id=14    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C             id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I             id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=12    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                      id=15    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here desmg output in bot cases:

```
[    1.708923] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: LEN2064 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
```

I tried to disable and enable id 13 with xinput command, but nothing happens...

Otherwise, best computer ever! Thanks for reading me.

Comment: `shutdown` means "power off", or "suspend"? What state does the power LED have? Also: Which devices are enabled to wake-up or power on the system?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot of messages about battery draining, I went back to the first thing I checked when I realized  the draining issue at the time : BIOS Settings.  And indeed, I thought I had already turn off WOL and USB-always-on (or something similar) settings, but I had not...
So now the draining is not an issue anymore and the power down method doesn't affect it.